# C++ construct a series of interdependant classes with no default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have classes A,B,C,D from a foreign library with no default constructors.

object A is given.
object D is required.

I can't write

```
D makeD(A a) {
  B b(1,2,3);
  C c(a,b);
  c.setParam1(4);
  c.setParam2(5);
  return D(a,b,c);
}
```

because the destruction of the intermediates B and C makes the returned D object unusable
(D stores B and C by reference).

what is the shortest solution to this problem?

One ugly and bad but short solution is this:

```
D makeD(A a) {
  B* b=new B(1,2,3);
  C* c=new C(a,*b);
  c->setParam1(4);
  c->setParam2(5);
  return D(a,*b,*c);
}
```

One long solution would be:

```
shared_ptr_xxl<D,B,C> makeD(A a) {
  B* b=new B(1,2,3);
  C* c=new C(a,*b);
  c->setParam1(4);
  c->setParam2(5);
  return shared_ptr_xxl<D,B,C>(new D(a,*b,*c),b,c);
}
```

where

```
shared_ptr_xxl<D,B,C>
```

is like

```
shared_ptr<D>
```

except it has additionaly has

```
delete b;
delete c;
```

in the destructor.

Comment: You mean that D stores B and C by reference or something? Hard to answer without knowing the structure of D.

Comment: … yeah, there seem to be a lot of unstated requirements. Are there also no copy constructors?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that contains them all:

```
class E {
    public:
        E(A const & a):
            b(1, 2, 3),
            c(make_c(a, b)),
            d(a, b, c)
            {
        }
    private:
        static C make_c(A const & a, B const & b) {
            C c(a, b);
            c.setParam1(4);
            c.setParam2(5);
            return c;
        }
        A a;
        B b;
        C c;
        D d;
};
```

Comment: D can't be constructed, since its only constructor depends on c, and c.setParam(3)... has to be performed

Comment: Your solution works, but I'm wondering if there's anything shorter/more generic.

Comment: You could use a C++11 solution with `std::tuple`, if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution is copying all the data:

```
void makeD(A a, D &d2) {
   B b(1,2,3);
   C c(a,b);
   c.setParam1(4);
   c.setParam2(5);
   D d(a,b,c);
   CopyFrom(d,d2);
}
```

But it obviously requires support from the foreign library... It helps if the foreign lib can publish all it's data structures via interface of the objects.

CopyFrom() will call member functions of d and copy the data to d2. In practise, it's often the case that d and d2 have different types..

Lets try this with std::vector:

```
void makeD(std::vector<int> &vec2) {
   std::vector<int*> vec;
   int a=10,b=20,c=30;
   vec.push_back(&a);
   vec.push_back(&b);
   vec.push_back(&c);
   CopyFrom(vec, vec2);
}
```

Then CopyFrom would look like:

```
void CopyFrom(std::vector<int*> vec, std::vector<int> &vec2) {
   for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) vec2.push_back(*vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: The problem persists, as objects B and C are still destructed.

Comment: user1350992: that's not a problem, since the same data still exists elsewhere - just in different form.

Comment: makeD is called - b,c are constructed, makeD finished - b,c are destructed. An object that holds a reference to destructed objects is returned

Comment: The objects need to store data, not just a reference. There is two separate representations of the data - one with references to other objects, and another where the refs are gone, and only data remains. This is clear from the std::vector example. This is why the interfaces of the objects must publish all data - so that new object can be created which has all the same data and implements same interface. If the object keeps it's data hidden or abstract, it will never work.

Comment: Additional comment, you shouldn't look at the lifetimes of the objects, but instead what data is available via interfaces of each object.

Comment: A,B,C,D come from foreign library. I would never write it like that, but I can't change it. Their usage pattern is: whenever an object D is required in a function - just paste the sequence from makeD in that function. And they don't copy data to make things "faster". It works, but the code is full of boilerplate and that's what I want to change.

Comment: @user1350992: Biggest problemm with function local scope is that the storage area of the local scope disappears after the function call is over. All data you want to preserve from that area must be copied away to some other scope for it to survive - or you need to use heap.